# Split TCP packet into smaller ones in AutoIT

Tags: tcp, packet, autoit

I try to send a simple HTTP GET Request using AutoIT TCPSend() command. The problem is that when I check the traffic using SmartSniff, everything is on the same line without linebreaks. 
My code is as follows:

```
        TCPStartup()
        $ip = "195.143.118.23"
        $port = "80"
        Global $tcp = TCPConnect($ip, $port)
        TCPSend($tcp, "GET  HTTP/1.1")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Host: ")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Connection: keep-alive")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Accept: ")
        TCPSend($tcp, "User-Agent: ")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Referer: ")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Accept-Encoding: ")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Accept-Language: ")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Cookie: ")
        TCPSend($tcp, "Connection: keep-alive")
        TCPCloseSocket($tcp)
```

Comment: Err.. OK, maybe add some linebreaks?

Comment: And note that the line terminator in HTTP is exactly `\r\n` (inherited from Telnet). Not `\n` or `\r` or `\n\r`.

Comment: Do I need to tell to the server somehow that my message has ended and that it is "server's turn"?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@CRLF` at the end of every string

Like

```
TCPSend($tcp,"Hello Line"&@CRLF)
```

It would also be better to send it once as one big string and not line by line

And don't close the socket.

If you want to get a respone fron the server, you have to use the function `TCPRecv`. After this you can close the socket.